# TextBox size update in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm using TextBox.
This picture when IsReadOnly = True
[image: Before]

After I'v set IsReadOnly = False
[image: Afler]

The problem that text is trimmed.
If I put few simbols, if become good size.
[image: Finish]

TextBox is a child of the grid. Grid row height is set to Auto.

How can I get good size when I set IsReadOnly = False?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what height you set for the TextBox (you should post that code and all the relevant information about it) I'd say you try giving it a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

This works good!

```
TextBox.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
TextBox.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), TextBox.DesiredSize));
```